# The way javascript compiler read line of code

Tags: javascript, performance, variables, scope

i am looking for the **order how the compiler reads the code.** is it reading the code from left to right or from right to left.
like

> `var a=b=c=100;`

in above code which variable will be declared first how the value will be assigned.?

Comment: Are you really asking how the compiler reads the code, in an interpreted language?

Comment: In the example you provided only one variable is declared (i.e. `a`). It is assigned the value `b` which is assigned the value `c` which is assigned the value `100`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider the example you provided:

```js
var a = b = c = 100;
```

This is equivalent to:

```js
var a;   // declare a

c = 100; // assign 100 to c
b = c;   // assign 100 to b via c
a = b;   // assign 100 to a via b
```

The thing is that in JavaScript if you assign a value to variable that you haven't declared then that variable becomes a global variable. That's the reason the above code works. However, it could also cause problems like in this example:

```js
console.log("a", typeof a); // undefined
console.log("b", typeof b); // undefined
console.log("c", typeof c); // undefined

function foo(x) {
    var a = b = c = x;
}

foo(100);

console.log("a", typeof a); // undefined
console.log("b", b); // 100
console.log("c", c); // 100
```

What you really want to do is:

```js
var a = 100, b = a, c = b;
```

This is equivalent to:

```js
var a, b, c; // all variables are hoisted

a = 100;
b = a;
c = b;
```

In JavaScript variable declarations are all [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to the top of the current scope (function scope for `var` and block scope for `const` and `let`). However, assignments happen in order from left to right. Variables which are declared but not assigned a value yet have the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

The following assignemt:

```
var a=b=c=100;
```

is equivalent to the following assignment:

```js
var a = (b = ( c= 100 ));
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

That being said it seems that the mulitple assigment is right associative.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence):

> Assignment operators are right-associative, so you can write:
>
> a = b = 5; with the expected result that a and b get the value 5. This
> is because the assignment operator returns the value that it assigned.
> First, b is set to 5. Then the a is also set to 5, the return value of
> b = 5, aka right operand of the assignment.

So for  `var a=b=c=100;`
first `c`, then `b` and then `a` will be assigned to `100`.

Comment: the thing Assignment operators are right-associative is bit new for me.now i gonna explore that..Thanks